# How can I change links made by hyperref?

Tags: hyperref, captions

My document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{mwrep}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[hidelinks,unicode]{hyperref}

\usepackage[T1,OT4]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hypcap}

\let\origfigure\figure
\let\endorigfigure\endfigure

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset\centering
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\chapter{Bzdety}\label{rozdzial-bzdety}
W rozdziale \ref{rozdzial-bzdety} ze strony \pageref{rozdzial-bzdety}
znajduje się obrazek \ref{obraz-jesien} na stronie \pageref{obraz-jesien}.

The first paragraph.

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{a.jpg}
    \caption[Opcjonalny skrócony opis do spisu obrazków]{Opis}
    \label{obraz-jesien}
\end{figure}

The second paragraph.
\end{document}
```

`hyerref` makes nice hyperlinks to captions of images. I can for example create list of figures. That is nice. But every link is going to caption and image is above it so reader needs to scroll up to see it. How can I change something in preamble so clicking on such hyperrlink leads to the top of image? I don't want to change anything outside preamble unless necessary.

Comment: `hyperref` should be loaded last but right before `hypcap`. It means no more `\usepackage` commands can exist after `\usepackage[]{hyperref}\usepackage{hypcap}`.

Comment: That's not precisely true: for example also **bookmark** should be loaded *after* **hyperref** (and it's advised to do this, since **bookmark** provides better bookmark management).

Comment: @Ichibann: The second version of your MWE allowed me to find an answer. Note, however, that the `draft` option has to be added to the `graphicx` package to make your example compilable if one lacks the file  `a.jpg`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Load `hypcap` with the `all` option: `\usepackage[all]{hypcap}`. See section 1.1 of the documentation for details.

EDIT: Here's a rather minimal working example (only the code for centering floats is retained):

```
\documentclass{mwrep}

\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset\centering
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\chapter{foo}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \includegraphics{a.jpg}
  \caption{Opis}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: OK, thanks. Why I'm getting `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package graphicx.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \usepackage` when trying to use `[draft]`? I'm sorry about MWE - I don't know exactly what should I leave and what can be ommitted :(

Comment: You mean in your "real" document? Possibly another package loads `graphicx` without options before you try to load it with the `draft` option. Try to move up `\usepackage[draft]{graphics}` in your preamble.

Comment: And you shouldn't be sorry about your MWE -- finding out what is relevant for the problem at hand often involves trial and error, and your second MWE version was much better than the first.

Comment: You were right:). I moved it up and it works :). Thanks!