# How do I make hyperref show the entire figure when I'm using both caption and floatrow?

Tags: captions, floatrow

I use the *caption* package in my document to control the appearance of captions on figures and tables (small text, with bold labels):

```
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
```

I use *hyperref* to make `\listoffigures` generate hyperlinks in the PDF. Captions are above their respective tables and figures in my document, and the hyperlinks correctly navigate such that the caption and figure are both visible on the screen.

This combination worked fine until I introduced *floatrow* to apply uniform formatting to the contents of figures and tables (small text, centered within margins, with caption still at the top):

```
\usepackage[font=small, margins=centering, style=plaintop]{floatrow}
```

With that addition, the hyperlinks navigate such that the caption is off the top of the screen. I've read about this problem before, but everything I've read ([example 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27096/1445), [example 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23260/1445)) advises either to use *caption* after *hyperref*, or to use the *hypcap* package. I'm already doing the former, and the latter had no effect. On the other hand, other instances of this issue all seem to be when the caption is *below* the image, and the *image* is off the screen, not the caption.

If I remove either *floatrow* or *caption*, the links go to the right places, but then of course I lose the corresponding format changes that each package provides. How can I get all the formatting I want, and still have links go to the right places?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[font=small, margins=centering, style=plaintop]{floatrow}

\usepackage{mwe, lipsum}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\clearpage

\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[h]
  % Links should navigate here.
  \caption{This is a figure}
  \label{figure1}
  % Links should not navigate here.
  \includegraphics{example-image}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unlike the OP's self-answer, it's a bit unreasonable for me to remove floatrow - so if anybody can come with another solution to this problem that'd be sweet!

Comment: I've opened a similar question to try and bring this back alive: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252773/hyperref-linking-below-tables-top-caption-when-floatrow-is-included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get *caption* and *floatrow* to work together, so I side-stepped the conflict by removing the latter package and implementing the requirements manually:

- Float contents should be centered, so take [some advice on how to automatically center an image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53383/1445) and modify `\@floatboxreset` in the document preamble:

  ```
  \makeatletter
  \g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset{\centering}
  \makeatother
  ```

  Or, a little more concisely using *etoolbox*:

  ```
  \gappto\@floatboxreset{\centering}
  ```
- Text in floats should be small; we can make that happen at the beginnings of the particular environments in use within the document. Again, using *etoolbox*:

  ```
  \BeforeBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\small}
  \BeforeBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\small}
  \BeforeBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{
      \tikzset{
          node font=\small,
      }
  }
  ```

  There is [a related question about changing the font size of figure legends](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64514/1445) in which answers involve solutions similar to the centering change described earlier, where we redefine or patch `\@floatboxreset`, but they didn't seem to work for me. My solution has the possible side effect of changing the font size of other document components that happen to use tabular environments (the author section of `\maketitle`, for example), but in my case, I was lucky enough to avoid any issues.