# hyperref link jumps beneath table's top caption when floatrow is included

Tags: tables, hyperref, captions, floatrow

I use the following packages related to captioning, tables and hyperlinks:

```
\usepackage{hyperref,caption}
\usepackage[style=Plaintop]{floatrow}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
```

I have a table and the caption appears ABOVE it. It's made using `threeparttable` so I can `\begin{tablenotes}`.

When I follow the link to that table, the view jumps to BELOW the caption - if you scroll just a tiny bit up then you'll see the caption straight away.

Of course, I want the caption to be seen without scrolling. If you remove the `\usepackage[...]{floatrow}` then it will work as expected.

I've tried using `hypcap` like most posts mention, but I believe use of `caption` covers that.

The only question I've found encountering the exact same problem (but with figures instead of tables) is this one: [How do I make hyperref show the entire figure when I'm using both caption and floatrow?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185711/how-do-i-make-hyperref-show-the-entire-figure-when-im-using-both-caption-and-fl)

As that OP mentioned, most other questions seem to be about the link going to the caption below a figure and hence missing the whole picture - this is not the same case at all. That OP managed to solve his problem by simply not using `floatrow` - I, however, cannot do that as I need that package for other purposes.

So how can I make the link work as I expected? Here's minimal code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref,caption}
\usepackage[style=Plaintop]{floatrow}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\begin{table}
    \begin{threeparttable}

        % Link SHOULD jump here

        \caption{Example}

        % Link ACTUALLY jumps here

        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            A & B \\
            C & D \\
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}
           \item ABCD
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

PS: If we can fix this within 4 hours of when the question was asked then I can include it in my Master's application :D

PPS: Made it with 35 minutes to spare thanks to @JohnKormylo!

Comment: Not sure what to make of that :P I'll change the title at least

Comment: I think your example doesn't help to reproduce the problem. But, in any case, did you try including `\label` inside `\caption`, `\caption{Example\label{Example}}`?

Comment: @Ignasi, if I copy and paste the above snippet into `test.tex` and `pdflatex test.tex && pdflatex test.tex` I get a PDF that accurately reproduces the problem in Mac OS X Preview. I tried putting the label inside caption as you recommended (before and after the caption's text) and nothing changed.

Comment: The target should the \refstepcounter in the caption, not the \label.  Besides, the \listoftables doesn't use the \label.

Comment: Good point @JohnKormylo (regarding the label - not sure about the `\refstepcounter`) - I removed the `\label` and it still happened. Apropos, I've removed it from the question.

Comment: @Christian Hupfer - The problem goes away when I remove floatrow.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I can vouch for @JohnKormylo here - when I tried to remove it the problem stopped occurring, so I added `floatrow` back to the title and tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evidently using `\ttabbox` put the target back where it belongs.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=Plaintop]{floatrow}
%\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[raiselinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\ref{Example}

\begin{table}[t]
    \ttabbox%
        % Link DOES jump here
        {
            \caption{Example}
            \label{Example}
        }
        % Link USED TO jump here
        {
            \begin{threeparttable}
                \begin{tabular}{ll}
                    A & B \\
                    C & D \\
                \end{tabular}
                \begin{tablenotes}
                    \item[a] ABCD
                \end{tablenotes}
            \end{threeparttable}
        }
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I use `threeparttable` and it's `\begin{tablenotes}` with this? Sorry, I'll update the question accordingly...

Comment: Nevermind, figured that out - it works! Marvelous! I just put the whole `threeparttable` in the `ttabbox`'s second `{}` (where you begin `tabular`) as normal, except with the caption and label as per your example. I'll try and edit it for you, if I can.

Comment: That edit is in - just needs peer review. Already accepted your answer though.

Comment: BTW, using \ttabbox[\textwidth] will allow the caption to be wider, assuming you wanted that.

Comment: Ahh the real table is wider, so that's not a worry. Good mention though.